# Firestore get single document using usEffect doesntt work

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I am trying to get a single document using useEffect but I don't know why when I'm trying to console log the data i don't get anything in browser console. But when I do it outside of useEffect then it logs `docRef` and `console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);`.

Here's my code:

```
export function MaterialCard() {
    const [material, setMaterial] = useState({});
    const location = useLocation()
    const { id } = useParams();


    useEffect(() => {
        const getDocument = async () => {
            try {
                const docRef = doc(db, "materials", id);
                console.log(docRef);
                const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
                    console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
                });

                if (docSnap.exists()) {
                    setMaterial(docSnap.data());
                } else {
                    console.log("No such document!");
                }
            } catch  (e) {
                console.log(e)
            };
            getDocument();
        }
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I spend so many hours to find the problem and I found out that i invoked function `getDocument` inside itself..